# How to compile with -Wall -02 and -std=c++0x

Tags: c++, g++

I want to compile with -`Wall -O2` and `-std=c++0x` . When I'm compiling without `-Wall -02` I have: `typeof was undeclared in this scope` and `it was undeclared in this scope`. When I'm compiling my code without a part of code that need `-std=c++0x` everything is okay, but I want this part. What's wrong?

Code that need `- Wall -O2` :

```
for(typeof(g[node].begin()) it = g[node].begin(); it != g[node].end(); ++it)
```

Code that need `-std=c++0x`:

`auto biggest = std::max_element(std::begin(koszty), std::end(koszty));`

and

`avg = accumulate(czasy.begin(), czasy.end(), 0) / czasy.size();`

Comment: BTW, you may upgrade your compiler and use `-std=c++11`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* and *unedited* error log, and then include the code that gives you the warnings.

Comment: First I think you mean `-O2` and not `-02` ; also have a look at http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: maybe you don't get typeof unless you are using -std=g++... in C it is a compiler extension, I don't know in C++

Comment: '-Wall -O2' irrelevant to the question. Do you want to compile one code with option '-std=c++0x' and another without it?

Comment: no i want to compile one code with all 3 options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* no such operator or keyword or standard function named `typeof`. It seems you are trying to use the C++11 [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) construct.

Even better might be to use the C++11 type-deduction using [`auto`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto):

```
for(auto it = g[node].begin(); it != g[node].end(); ++it)
```

Or maybe a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for):

```
for (auto& val : g[node]) { ... }
```

And like a comment says, the options you want to use are not incompatible, use all of them if needed or wanted.

Comment: There *was* a `typeof` extension in g++ compiler. `decltype` etc. resulted from that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no identifier `typeof` mentioned in ISO C++. It is [a GNU extension for C and C++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html)
. It's irrelevant to `-Wall`(an option to control warning) or `-O2`(an option to control optimization). You should use `-std=gnu++0x` instead of `-std=c++0x` to enable the GNU dialect, if really needed.

However, it seems to be unnecessary. Since you are using C++0x (now C++11), the keyword `decltype` is the right and conforming replacement of `typeof`. But here I suggest to use `auto` for clarity.